# Migrated my C# application from one machine to another and there is some issue in connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I changed my machine/laptop on which I was developing a C# application. The application was running without any SQL Server or connection based issues/problems. Now that I am continuing with the rest of development on the other machine. Although I was using the connection string like:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=local; database=hospital; integrated security= true");
```

but now this connection string is not working and an exception is being shown as:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)*

I dont know what is this issue raised with. May be due to a new server name(but I am using "server=." which means that it will connect with the local server. Or there may be some issue with the installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 ). Help me out,Please!!!

Comment: If your sql server is running then there might be some privilege issues.

Comment: I doubt, may be there is something wrong with my installation of SQL Server2008 R2.

Comment: I dont exactly remember what was specified during the installation on the previous machine. Was it a Mixed Mode Configuration or a Windows Authentication

Comment: Open Management Studio and login with windows authentication. Then verify the name of your database. I don't see any problem with your connection string.

Comment: I opened the Mgmt Studio and it is already logging in with Windows Mode. The Sql Server Management Studio is compatible with the databases. It is reflecting no change as with my previous machine. But the Visual Studio is giving this exception

Comment: Right click on the instance that is currently running. Go to property->security and check which authentication mode is selected.

Comment: It is only the Windows Authentication Mode.... The log in auditing is in Failed Logins only.

Comment: Also check the security setting in the tree view of databases. Your current user should be listed there. For example: `servername\Administrator`

Comment: If you want to reference the SQL Server on the local machine, you need to use `.` or `(local)` (in **brackets!** - not just `local`). Right now, you're trying to connect to a machine called `local` - which might not exist .....

Comment: you can write `localhost` instead of `local`.

Comment: there are 4 users there. DBO, guest, sys, INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: I changed the keyword local to localhost. Now the exception comes out like:
Cannot open database "hospital" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Dell-PC\Dell'.

Comment: Ok. We are getting somewhere now. Now, in security node->Login click on search and add current user which is `Dell-PC\Dell`

Comment: Can you describe the path from where it is to be done

Comment: where is this security node?

Comment: Check the image that I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Checkout this image. This is how you can add the current user.

**Security->right cick Logins->Select New Login->Click on Search** and you will get that window.

Comment: After entering `Dell-PC\Dell`, click on Check Names. See if any error is popping up there.

Comment: Create failed for login DELL-PC\DELL.
The server Principal already exists.DELL-PC\DELL

Comment: When I clicked Check Names, No errors get observed. All that the DELL-PC\DELL gets underlined

Comment: What can we do next to get through it. My whole application will be destroyed or if I have to change the connection string, Please tell me.

Comment: When you expand login, do you see `Dell-PC\Dell` there? If yes then right click on Dell-PC\Dell->select Properties->select Status. Now what do you see in the right side of the window? **Grant** and **Enabled** should be selected there.

Comment: You know in my previous machine I was using the connection string as:
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; database=hospital; integrated security= true");

Comment: I was using a . instead of the keyword Local or localhost

Comment: What is the name of the database it is showing in the databases?

Comment: my database is hospital
and it is also showing the System Databases

Comment: You doing some research over it or what?

Comment: Check `allow remote connection property` in instance's property window.

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=troubleshooting%20database%20connection%20errors

Comment: Your link is a connection specification search on Google. I dont feel any assistance by those links as my problem seems to be out of this. If I could send to you my project along with the databases, it would be great assistance